Unexpected error in Excel VBA: Run-time error '424'. Object required
I have a subroutine that adds an item to a Collection only if that item is not present. This effectively treats Collections as if they are sets.
But VBA returns error 424 when the subroutine is called.
Private Sub SetUnion(ByVal e As String, ByVal Coll As Collection)
found = False
For n = 1 To Coll.Count
    If Coll(n) = e Then
        found = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next n
If found = False Then Coll.Add e
End Sub

When I call it with
Dim s1, C  As Collection
For n = 1 To s1.Count
SetUnion s1(n), C   #
Next n

I get
Run-time error ‘424’:
Object required

What have I done wrong?

Dim s1 means it will be a Variant, and Variants do not have a Count property. It looks kinda like you are confusing your variables with each other.

Also, not sure if that # in your code is just a typo, but it doesn't belong there either.

Thanks @brax but s1 is a Collection, not a String and the # was just a misprint. But I think I see the problem now.

@BernardCohen But you've never declared s1 to be a Collection; nor have you ever set s1 as a Collection. What makes you think it is a collection?

It’s declared as a Collection at the start of the code, which I didn’t include. But don’t worry, I’ve fixed it.


@braX commented that you've used syntax from another programming language in your VBA code.

Based on your code, it seems you're attempting to extract the unique characters from a string.


Option Explicit

Sub SetUnion(ByVal e As String, ByRef Coll As Collection)
    Dim n As Long
    If Not Coll Is Nothing Then
        For n = 1 To Coll.Count
            If Coll(n) = e Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next n
    End If
    Coll.Add e
End Sub

Sub test()
    Dim sStr As String, oCol  As Collection, n As Long
    sStr = "abcabd"
    Set oCol = New Collection
    For n = 1 To Len(sStr)
        SetUnion Mid(sStr, n, 1), oCol
    Next n
    For n = 1 To oCol.Count
        Debug.Print oCol(n)
    Next
End Sub

Output:
a
b
c
d



Use less code lines with Dictionary object

Sub test2()
    Dim sStr As String, vKey
    Dim objDic As Object, n As Long
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    sStr = "abcabd"
    For n = 1 To Len(sStr)
        vKey = Mid(sStr, n, 1)
        If Not objDic.exists(vKey) Then
            Debug.Print vKey
            objDic(vKey) = ""
        End If
    Next n
    For Each vKey In objDic
        ' your code
    Next
End Sub


I believe it can be shorter using the Collection object. For the loop: For n = 1 To Len(sStr): vKey = Mid(sStr, n, 1): On Error Resume Next: col.Add vKey, vKey: On Error GoTo 0: Next n
